# Characterize all the continuous functions that satisfy the following condition

Tags: integration, riemann-integration, constants

Characterize all the continuous functions $f$ in $[a,b]$ that satisfy
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,\varphi(x)\,dx = 0$$
$\forall\,\varphi(x)$ continuous in $[a,b]$ such that $\int_a^b \varphi(x)\,dx = 0$.
I understood that the condition is verified by constant function, but I don't know how to prove it. I tried for *reductio ad absurdam*, but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Hmm. Looks like $f(x)=1$ works, as well as $f(x)=0.$ Not sure there are any others. Or you might be able to do something with the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma.

Comment: The professor didn't explain that lemma, sorry

Comment: Actually, $f(x)=\text{const}$ works.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

If $\Phi$ is the set of all functions $\phi(x)$ whose integral over $[a,b]$ is null, then in particular
$$
\sin \left( {\omega \left( {x - {{a + b} \over 2}} \right)} \right)\quad \left| {\;\forall \omega  \ne 0} \right.
$$
belong to $\Phi$.

Fourier series …

*--- following your comment  --*

Consider the functions $\phi \in \Phi$ which are continuous in $[a,b]$ and odd wrt the midpoint of the segment.
Then $f(x)$ shall be even over $[a,(a+b)/2,b]$.

Now consider the functions which are continuous over all $[a,b]$,  odd wrt a sub-segment therein, and null outside: then 
$f(x)$ shall be even over such a sub-segment.

We conclude that $f(x)$ must be even over all $[a,b]$ and any sub-segment of it, i.e. $f(x)=const$.

Comment: I didn't study that arguments, i'm in the first calculus course